# JSJaC + Openfire: no connection with some users

Tags: javascript, xmpp, openfire, jsjac

ok, I'm finally at my wits' end. I have a have an XMPP server (Openfire) running, and trying to connect via JavaScript using JSJaC. The strange thing is that I can establish a connection for some users, but not for all. I can reproduce the following behavior: create two accounts (username/password), namely r/pwd and rr/pwd with the result:

r/pwd works

rr/pwd doesn't work.

So far, each account with a user name consisting of only one character works. This is strange enough. On the other side, old accounts, e.g., alice/a work. The whole connection problem is quite new, and I cannot trace it to any changes I've made.

And to make my confusion complete with any instant messenger supporting XMPP, all accounts work, incl., e.g., rr/pwd. So assume, the error must be somewhere in my JavaScript code. Here's he relevant snippet:

```
  ...
  oArgs = new Object();
  oArgs.domain = this.server;
  oArgs.resource = this.resource;
  oArgs.username = "r";
  oArgs.pass = "pwd";
  this.connection.connect(oArgs);
```

The code above works, but setting oArgs.username = "rr", and it fails.

I would be grateful for any hints. I'm quite sure that it must be something really stupid I miss here.

Christian

Comment: It works, when I add the following line `oArgs.authtype = 'nonsasl';`. While this is good enough for the moment, I would still like to understand what the problem was/is. I appreciate any hints.

Comment: Enable SASL in Openfire?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `oArgs.authtype = 'nonsasl'` to the argument list when creating the xmpp connection using JSJaC solved my problem. I haven't tried Joe's command to alter the SASL settings in Openfire; I'm scared to ruing my running system :).